# Replace in array of zeros with other values in certain cells_updated question

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, matrix

I need to solve a problem in which I have spent hours, with the data from my excel sheet I have created a 6x36 '' zeros '' matrix of zeros and a 6x6 '' matrix_tran '' coordinate transformation matrix [image 1].
[image]

My problem is that I can't find a way to replace the zeros of the '' zeros '' matrix with the values that the matrix '' matrix_tran '' dictates, and whose location must be in the columns (4,5,6, 7,8,9) that are given by the connection vector (4,5,6,7,8,9) of element 15 of the Excel sheet, that is, the last row of the for loop iteration [image 2].
[image]

In summary: Below I show how it fits and how it should look [image 3 and 4 respectively]. 
[image]

I would very much appreciate your help, and excuse my English, but it is not my native language, a big greeting.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

ex = pd.ExcelFile('matrix_tr.xlsx')
hoja = ex.parse('Hoja1')

cols = 36

for n in range(0,len(hoja)):
    A = hoja['ELEMENT #'][n]
    B = hoja['1(i)'][n]
    C = hoja['2(i)'][n]
    D = hoja['3(i)'][n]
    E = hoja['1(j)'][n]
    F = hoja['2(j)'][n]
    G = hoja['3(j)'][n]
    H = hoja['X(i)'][n]  
    I = hoja['Y(i)'][n]
    J = hoja['X(j)'][n]  
    K = hoja['Y(j)'][n]

    L = np.sqrt((J-H)**2+(K-I)**2)
    lx = (J-H)/L
    ly = (K-I)/L

    zeros = np.zeros((6, cols))

    counters = hoja.loc[:, ["1(i)", "2(i)", "3(i)", "1(j)", "2(j)", "3(j)"]]
    for _, i1, i2, i3, j1, j2, j3 in counters.itertuples(): 


        matrix_tran = np.array([[lx,  ly,    0,    0,    0,    0],
                                [-ly, lx,    0,    0,    0,    0],
                                [0,    0,    1,    0,    0,    0],
                                [0,    0,    0,   lx,   ly,    0],
                                [0,    0,    0,  -ly,   lx,    0],
                                [0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1]])

        zeros[:, [i1 - 1, i2 - 1, i3 - 1, j1 - 1, j2 - 1 , j3 - 1]] = matrix_tran
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with a transposed zeros matrix

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

ex = pd.ExcelFile('c:/tmp/SO/matrix_tr.xlsx')
hoja = ex.parse('Hoja1')
counters = hoja.loc[:, ["1(i)", "2(i)", "3(i)", "1(j)", "2(j)", "3(j)"]]

# zeros matrix transposed
cols = 36
zeros_trans = np.zeros((cols,6))

# last row only
for n in range(14,len(hoja)):

    Xi = hoja['X(i)'][n]  
    Yi = hoja['Y(i)'][n]
    Xj = hoja['X(j)'][n]  
    Yj = hoja['Y(j)'][n]
    X = Xj-Xi
    Y = Yj-Yi
    L = np.sqrt(X**2+Y**2)
    lx = X/L
    ly = Y/L
    matrix_tran = np.array([[lx,  ly,    0,    0,    0,    0],
                           [-ly, lx,    0,    0,    0,    0],
                           [0,    0,    1,    0,    0,    0],
                           [0,    0,    0,   lx,   ly,    0],
                           [0,    0,    0,  -ly,   lx,    0],
                           [0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1]])

    i = 0
    for r in counters.iloc[n]:
        zeros_trans[r-1] = matrix_tran[i]
        i += 1  

print(np.transpose(zeros_trans))
```

Comment: Thanks friend, you gave me an idea.